# How to select and copy content in Tmux?

Tags: ssh, tmux, iterm2

I am using iTerm2 and attach to a ssh TMUX session as `ssh -YCt ssh_server tmux a`.

Now how could I select and copy the content in the terminal?

I can't select with mouse.

Answer (score 2):

The simple way is to press Option (Alt) button when copying, and now you can copy as if Tmux doesn’t exist!

source:
http://www.rushiagr.com/blog/2016/06/16/everything-you-need-to-know-about-tmux-copy-pasting/